# Attempting to play a sound in Minecraft results in [Client thread/WARN]: Unable to play unknown soundEvent

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have a program to play a sound when a regex is matched for an unformatted message

```java
@SubscribeEvent
    public void ChatRecieved(ClientChatReceivedEvent event) {
        String message = event.message.getUnformattedText();
        Matcher m = regex.matcher(message);
        if (m.matches()) {
            Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.playSound("BazaarAlert:sound", 1, 1);
        }
    }
```

However, the sound doesn't play and

```
[Client thread/WARN]: Unable to play unknown soundEvent: bazaaralert:sound
```

is sent to the console.
Here is my sounds.json:

```json
{
    "sound": {
        "category": "ambient",
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "sound",
                "stream": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is how my project is formatted in Eclipse:

[image: Here is how my project is formatted in Eclipse.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot have a namespace (like BazaarAlert) that has capital letters and the sounds.json just needs the name for ones with

```json
stream: false
```

Use Luca100's ResourceLocation solution just with the first name of the JSON. 
Ex:

```json
{
    "whatever_you_want_the_sound_to_be_name": {
        "category": "category",
        "sounds": [
            {"file"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Would be

```java
Minecraft.getMinecraft().getSoundHandler().playSound(PositionedSoundRecord.create(new ResourceLocation(this.MODID, "sound"), 1.0F));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using resource locations: `Minecraft.getMinecraft().getSoundHandler().playSound(PositionedSoundRecord.create(new ResourceLocation("your/resource/here.ogg")));`

Comment: I used `Minecraft.getMinecraft().getSoundHandler().playSound(PositionedSoundRecord.create(new ResourceLocation("BazaarAlert:sound")));` with the same setup in the picture and same sound.json. It outputs the same warning. Is there something I'm doing wrong?